# JERSEY RESTful - How to work with multiselect checkboxes?

Tags: rest, jersey, multi-select

I´m trying to create a method that receive a list of parameters from a multiselection checkbox html component. But, it just doesn´t work.

I've test:

```
@POST..
.. myMethod(@FormParam String [] myCheckboxAttribute)
.. myMethod(@FormParam List<String> myCheckboxAttribute)
```

None of those works well (the last one (list) come with just the first checkbox checked but the others no).

Some idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to specify the name of the form parameter in the @FormParam annotation.

Here is an example that works for me:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String postForm(@FormParam("param") List<String> param) {
    return param.toString();
}
```

HTML form:

```
<html><body>
<form action="http://localhost:9998/myresource" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="param" value="a">A</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="param" value="b">B</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="param" value="c">C</input>
<input type="submit">OK</input>
</form>
</body></html>
```

Submitting the form with B and C checked prints out:

```
[b, c]
```

I also verified in the debugger that the list is populated with 2 strings, b and c.

Comment: That's mental, i spent few hours trying to understand why `param[0]=123&param[1]=234` doesn't work. Jersey is actually waiting for a  `param=123&param=234`